# OpenJFX 14 with maven and IntelliJ : Cannot run application

Tags: java, maven, openjfx, java-14

I am trying to use OpenJFX on a JDK 14 Java project on IntelliJ.
My project has multiple IntelliJ modules that each have a pom.xml.

In the IntelliJ Module that contains my main I have added JFX as dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>14</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

And in my top-level pom.xml I have added the JFX plugin :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>fr.efrei.wiemetarsene.caspersky.app.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when I try to run my app with :

```
mvn javafx:run
```

Il get the following error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:run (default-cli) on project caspersky: Error: Output directory is empty, compile first -> [Help 1]
```

I tried to run :

```
mvn compiler:compile
```

before doing that but the result is exactly the same. Do you have any clue about why it's not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 13: Why are javaFX runtime components missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512068/java-13-why-are-javafx-runtime-components-missing)

Comment: Wrong value of packaging in pom.xml could cause empty output, such as "pom", especially in multiple modules project. I mean some refactor operations may have happened which changed packaging value from "jar" into "pom" unconsciously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have multi module javafx project and I met the same error. Main class is in my View module. In pom file I have:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>14</source>
        <target>14</target>
        <release>14</release>
        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

then in terminal type:

```
mvn install
cd View
mvn javafx:run
```

After making some changes in my code I often receive some strange errors like missing components. Then repeating above steps is fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From there [README](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxcompile-options), you can try out the following changes:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>14</source>
        <target>14</target>
        <release>14</release>
        <mainClass>fr.efrei.wiemetarsene.caspersky.app.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and further, compile your project using

```
mvn javafx:compile
```

but since the [docs might be outdated](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/81), you can try executing

```
mvn compile
```

or

```
mvn clean javafx:jlink
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I just tried but maven threw this error to me : " Could not find goal 'compile' in plugin org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4"

Comment: @Ombrelin yeah, seems like there doc is outdated, see the edit in the answer.

Comment: I've tried both, mvn clean javafx:jlink give me "NullPointerExcep
tion"and mvn compile give me "invalid target release: 14"